# How to hide <select>

Tags: semantic-ui

```
<select class='ui selection dropdown' name='YearLevel' style="display:none" id='YearLevel'>
  <option value=''>Year Level</option>
  <option value='II'>I</option>
  <option value='II'>II</option>
  <option value='III'>III</option>
  <option value='IV'>IV</option>
</select>
<style>
 select#YearLevel{
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

I tried everything I know but it just wouldn't work.

Comment: What is the issue ? Can you re-phrase?

Comment: The <select> wont hide itself. Its visible. I need it hidden until a JQuery event is triggered

Comment: wrap it in a div with an id and try hiding the div

Comment: Solved it with .dropdown().hide(); and .dropdown().show()